# Cursor not appearing in Editfield in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Cursor is not appearing in Editfield..

Following is the code..

```java
ef_mob = new EditField("", "", 11, EditField.NO_NEWLINE|EditField.FILTER_NUMERIC|EditField.FOCUSABLE) {
   protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
      graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      // graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-(getWidth()/10), getHeight(), 5, 5);

      graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-(getWidth()/10), getHeight(), 5, 5);
      graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);

      graphics.drawText(ef_mob.getText(), 0, 0);
      super.paint(graphics);
   }
};
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Could give an idea what do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kind of silly that it's so much work just to properly draw a rounded rectangle background on an `EditField`, but it looks like [others have had this problem, too](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Cursor-Caret-not-appearing-in-EditField/m-p/553556#M112688)

### Solution One

If you adapt Peter Strange's answer to that question, your code might look like the `MobEditField` posted below.  I split your anonymous `EditField` class into a separate class, since a lot of code was added.  If you really want, you could keep the code as an anonymous class (which I think is really bad for readability).

```java
private class MobEditField extends EditField {
    private boolean _drawFocus = false;

    public MobEditField() {
        super("", "", 11, EditField.NO_NEWLINE|EditField.FILTER_NUMERIC|EditField.FOCUSABLE);
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        if (!_drawFocus) {
            int oldColor = graphics.getColor();

            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth() - (getWidth() / 10), getHeight(), 5, 5);

            graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            graphics.drawText(getText(), 0, 0);

            graphics.setColor(oldColor);
        }
        super.paint(graphics);
    }

    protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
        _drawFocus = on;
        super.drawFocus(graphics, on);
        _drawFocus = false;
    }

    protected void onFocus( int direction ) {
        super.onFocus( direction );
        invalidate();
    }

    protected void onUnfocus() {
        super.onUnfocus();
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

then you just do:

```java
ef_mob = new MobEditField();
```

Take note of a few things:

1. Don't call `ef_mob.getText()` from within the anonymous class's `paint()` method.  Just call `getText()`.  I don't know how your original code even compiled.
2. It's best, when overriding the `paint()` method, to save off the initial `Graphics` object color (or alpha, or whatever you change), and then reset it at the end.
3. The `onFocus()` and `onUnfocus()` methods are overridden to force repainting
4. The `paint()` method just lets `super.paint()` do all the work when the field is focused. Depending on how you want your field to look, you may need to adjust this a little.

### Solution Two

Another alternative that worked for me is to take advantage of the **undocumented** `paintBackground()` method, that `EditField` has.  Of course, there's always downsides to using undocumented methods.  So, I offer it only as an option:

```java
        ef_mob = new EditField("", "", 11, EditField.NO_NEWLINE|EditField.FILTER_NUMERIC|EditField.FOCUSABLE) {
            protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                int oldColor = graphics.getColor();

                graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                graphics.drawText(getText(), 0, 0);

                graphics.setColor(oldColor);
                super.paint(graphics);
            }

            protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
                int oldColor = g.getColor();
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-(getWidth()/10), getHeight(), 5, 5);
                g.setColor(oldColor);
            }

        };
```

Here, I moved the `fillRoundRect()` call out of `paint()` and into `paintBackground()`.

Comment: Good answer. I usually use `paintBackground()` too. It works for me all the way.

Comment: Why don't use `setBackground`, `setBorder` methods? Also calling `super.paint()` will draw text so you don't need `drawText` in your code.

Comment: @Nate Thanks a lot for ur reply...  I have used your solution one with some changes..now cursor is appearing.. In paint method, i make some changes.. `protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
     if ( _drawFocus ) {
         super.paint(graphics);
         return;
       }
     int oldColor = graphics.getColor();
     
      graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-(getWidth()/10), getHeight(), 5, 5);
      graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    super.paint(graphics);
     graphics.setColor(oldColor);
   }`  **Thanks a lot For Guide me correctly..**

Comment: @EugenMartynov, yeah, I generally agree about `drawText()` not being necessary.  It was in the original posted code, so I left it there.  Even though the original code was just using black font, I thought it might be a placeholder to later do some different things with the text color.  In terms of `setBackground`, I would assume the reason Kinjal stayed away from that was because of wanting to draw the **rounded rectangle** background.  If it was just a solid color, I would definitely recommend using `setBackground`, too.

Comment: @Nate I missed this point (have to read code carefully). there are still possibility to use background methods for rounded rect (use bitmap background) but it requires more effor and much easier draw it every time.

Comment: @Nate  Hey if u have any idea regarding blackberry devices resolution then plz visit this link and help me.. Thanks in advance.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153613/blackberry-resolution