# BlackBerry Resolution

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-playbook

Is there any simulator with Resolution 680x800 in BlackBerry?

I have searched a lot..But I could not get specific Result..

Site from which I download Simulaors does not provide Resolution information..

http://swdownloads.blackberry.com/Downloads/contactFormPreload.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477&dl=7A51789FDE2B3B44C6ED1BA5D80D53CB&check1=A

Please Help me...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't remember any particular device with such resolution. So I'm assuming there is no simulators with such resolution.

Comment: @EugenMartynov..I think..you are Right..Thanks a lot..

Comment: If you mean 800x480, yes: the Torch 9850/9860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that there is a BlackBerry device with that resolution.
Here is a list of some legacy BB devices: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/List-of-Blackberry-Devices-with-resolution/td-p/556066

BlackBerry Playbook uses 1024 x 600.
Z10 is 768 x 1280
Q10 is 720 x 720

Also, there are no results on gsmarena.com for devices with a "680 x 800" or "800 x 680" screens.